# Infinite loading screen in React when trying to use a component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a hamburger menu to my existing live chat app. I have wrapped what I want to be inside the hamburger menu in FarSideBar.js, it is wrapped in 'Ul' in the return. Now in my Burger.js I need to use the `<FarSideBar open={open} />`  component but as soon as I use FarSideBar at all I get a never-ending loading screen. I will also leave the code for FarSideBarOption.js as I originally tried to implement this in that file with Burger.js and the functionality worked but the only thing that moved when I clicked the burger was the first hashtag becuase it was set up like this in the return:

```
 return (
        <div className="farSidebarOption" onClick={addChannelOptions ? addChannel : selectChannel}>
            <Ul open={open}>
            {Icon && <Icon className="farSidebarOption_icon"/>}
            {Icon ? (
                
                <h3> {title} </h3>
                
            ): (
                <h3 className="farSidebarOption__channel">
                   <span className="farSidebarOption__hash"># {title}</span>
                </h3>
                
            )}
            </Ul>
        </div>
    )
```

and Burger.js looked like:

```
const Burger = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  
  return (
    <>
      <StyledBurger open={open} onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
        <div />
        <div />
        <div />
      </StyledBurger>
      <FarSideBarOption open={open}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

So I switched to putting the Ul wrap in FarSideBar.js:

```
 return (
        <div className="farSidebar">
            <div className="farSidebar__header">
                <div className="farSidebar__header__info">
                    <h2 >Discord</h2>
                    <h1 className="farSideBar__header__info__hamburger"><Burger /></h1>
                    <h3>
                        {user?.displayName}
                    </h3>

                        

                </div>
                <Ul open={open}>
                        <FarSideBarOption  title="myself"  Icon={AlarmOnIcon}/>
                        <FarSideBarOption  title="wow"  Icon={AlarmOnIcon}/>
                        <FarSideBarOption  title="add"  Icon={AlarmOnIcon} addChannelOptions/>
                
                
                {channels.map(channel => (
                    <FarSideBarOption title={channel.name} id={channel.id} />
                ))}
                </Ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

And now all the items I want in the hamburger originals start off to the side, but as soon as I try to pass `<FarSdieBar />` into Burger.js to complete the functionality I get the infinite loading screen. Here is the full code:

Burger.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import FarSideBarOption from './FarSideBarOption.js';
import FarSideBar from './FarSideBar';

const StyledBurger = styled.div`
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 20;
  display: none;

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
  }

  div {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 0.25rem;

    /* Hamburger symbol color change */
    background-color: ${({ open }) => open ? '#ccc' : '#333'};

    border-radius: 10px;
    transform-origin: 1px;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;


  /** Hamburger symbol animation **/

    &:nth-child(1) {
      transform: ${({ open }) => open ? 'rotate(45deg)' : 'rotate(0)'};
    }

    &:nth-child(2) {
      transform: ${({ open }) => open ? 'translateX(100%)' : 'translateX(0)'};
      opacity: ${({ open }) => open ? 0 : 1};
    }

    &:nth-child(3) {
      transform: ${({ open }) => open ? 'rotate(-45deg)' : 'rotate(0)'};
    }

  }
`;

const Burger = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  
  return (
    <>
      <StyledBurger open={open} onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
        <div />
        <div />
        <div />
      </StyledBurger>
      <FarSideBar open={open}/>
    </>
  )
}

export default Burger
```

FarSideBar.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { useStateValue } from "../StateProvider";
import db from '../firebase';
import FarSideBarOption from '../components/FarSideBarOption';
import { AlarmOnIcon }  from '@material-ui/icons/AlarmOn';
import '../CSS/main.scss'
import Burger from './Burger'
import styled from 'styled-components';

const FarSideBar = ({ open }) => {
  

    const Ul = styled.ul`

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      background-color: #0D2538;
      transform: ${({ open }) => open ? 'translateX(0)' : 'translateX(110%)'};
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
      color: #fff;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
  `;

    const [channels, setChannels] = useState([]);
    const [{ user }] = useStateValue();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('rooms').onSnapshot(snapshot => (
            setChannels(
                snapshot.docs.map(doc =>
                    ({
                        id: doc.id,
                        name: doc.data().name
                    }))
            )
        ))
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="farSidebar">
            <div className="farSidebar__header">
                <div className="farSidebar__header__info">
                    <h2 >Discord</h2>
                    <h1 className="farSideBar__header__info__hamburger"><Burger /></h1>
                    <h3>
                        {user?.displayName}
                    </h3>

                        

                </div>
                <Ul open={open}>
                        <FarSideBarOption  title="myself"  Icon={AlarmOnIcon}/>
                        <FarSideBarOption  title="wow"  Icon={AlarmOnIcon}/>
                        <FarSideBarOption  title="add"  Icon={AlarmOnIcon} addChannelOptions/>
                
                
                {channels.map(channel => (
                    <FarSideBarOption title={channel.name} id={channel.id} />
                ))}
                </Ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default FarSideBar
```

FarSideBarOption.js

```
import React from 'react'
import '../CSS/main.scss'
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import db from '../firebase';
import styled from 'styled-components';



function FarSideBarOption({ id, title, addChannelOptions, Icon} ) {


    const history = useHistory();


    const selectChannel = () => {
        if(id) {
            history.push(`/room/${id}`)
        } else {
            history.push(title);
        }
    }

    const addChannel = () => {
        const channelName = prompt('Please enter the channel name')

        if (channelName) {
            db.collection('rooms').add({
                name: channelName
            })
        }
    }


    return (
        <div className="farSidebarOption" onClick={addChannelOptions ? addChannel : selectChannel}>
            {Icon && <Icon className="farSidebarOption_icon"/>}
            {Icon ? (
                
                <h3> {title} </h3>
                
            ): (
                <h3 className="farSidebarOption__channel">
                   <span className="farSidebarOption__hash"># {title}</span>
                </h3>
                
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default FarSideBarOption
```

Comment: Does db.collection in FarSideBar.js (useEffect()) need to be async?

Comment: Where would  I put the aysnc / await in the useEffect to test it out?

Comment: this might help https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/handling-api-calls-using-async-await-in-useeffect-hook-990fb4ae423

Comment: I was reading about using async with useEffect and it makes sense. The problem is I do not know where to put it in this function as everything I read included putting the async/await right after naming a const. The db.collection is not set up like that

Comment: For example```useEffect(async () => {
  const users = await axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?page=1&results=10&nat=us");
  setUsers(users.data.results);
}, []);```